# 404 response from JQuery call to MVC Action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

When trying to call an MVC Action from JQuery (using @Url.Action) I am getting a 404 error

```
$(function () {
$('#propertyCombo').change(function () {

    var id = $('#propertyCombo option:selected').val();
    alert(id);

    $.post('@Url.Action("PropertyHasChanged", "Bookings"', null, function (data) {
        // handle the server response here
    }).done(function () {
        alert("success");
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, exception) {
        alert(exception);
        alert(jqXHR.status);
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    }).error
});
```

The controller code is

```
   public class BookingsController : BaseController
   {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        public ActionResult PropertyHasChanged()
        {
            return null;
        }
```

The breakpoint in the controller is never hit and a 404 error is returned. I tried naming the "Bookings" controller in the JQuery "BookingsController" and that did not work either.

I suspect it is something very basic I am missing?

Comment: Looks like a typo to me. Where is the closing `)`?

Comment: I have tried everything that has been said below and I am still getting the same 404 error. I must have done something wrong in the setup or something. I suppose my next step is to learn Ajax. Will post update when I figure it out

Comment: Using either your browser's native developer tools (usually accessed on a Windows PC by hitting the F12 key) or Firebug, observe the URL that $.post is trying to POST to. I'm fairly sure that you'll see what @Shyju is suggesting is true: you have an error in your Razor syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a few things wrong..

if you're doing a `post`, your action needs to have the `[HttpPost]` attribute

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PropertyHasChanged()
{
    return Content("Success!");
}
```

I know `$.post()` is short hand but use the `$.ajax()` version so you can see what options your passing in a little easier

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("PropertyHasChanged","Bookings")",
    type: "POST",
    data: {id: id}
}).done(function(data){
    // handle the server response here
    alert(data);
}).fail(function (jqXHR, exception) {
    alert(exception);
    alert(jqXHR.status);
    alert(jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

Comment: I had to use Chrome developer tools which gave me a 404 error. With the above answer i fixed my problem. (Internet explorer did not give me the 404 error for some reason)

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a problem creating the url to the action method in your script. From the code you posted, you are missing the closing bracket of `Url.Action` method.

The below code should work fine.

```
var myUrl='@Url.Action("PropertyHasChanged", "Bookings")';

alert(myUrl);

$.post(myUrl, function (data) {

    alert("response received from server");

    // handle the server response here
});
```